# A MySQL Event should run once every month at the 1st day's 00:00:00 (Midnight)

Tags: mysql, database, events, scheduled-tasks, mysql-event

I have Win XP os and XAMPP installed in my machine.

I need to run my event at `00:00:00`(Midnight) of the 1st day of every month.
Means 1st of every month. (e.g. jan 1st, Feb1 1st, March 1st, ... ).

And, I also need to call the stored procedure in the same event.
And I want achieve all this using Event/Job only not from front end.

Please spend few minutes for my query.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The MySQL event syntax is very simple -

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2011-05-01 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 -- your code
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Event will start working on '2011-05-01' at '00:00:00' (datetime must be in a future).

More information - [Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Do not forget to enable global event scheduling thread -

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Devart, And could you let me know how to SET enable the  GLOBAL event_scheduler;

Comment: Just run 'SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;'. You can check its status with this command - 'SHOW PROCESSLIST;'.

Comment: Please how to find the jobs which are running in the machine please. I need to disable it.The job is keep on inserting the data into the table.

Comment: See ALTER EVENT syntax, e.g. - 'ALTER EVENT event1 DISABLE;'.

Comment: Your Job/Event is working fine. But I am unable to stop that event. I need to stop it sir.

Comment: Try to set full name - 'ALTER EVENT `db_name`.`event_name` DISABLE;'. Also, you can drop it - 'DROP EVENT `db_name`.`event_name`;'.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Devart, You Have helped me nicely. Greate Response instantly.

Comment: I have checked. Works for me. Another thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728996/event-is-not-working-properly-in-mysql

Comment: I want to start event every 1st day of every month (Exactly at 12:00:00 AM).

Comment: @Devart sorry for comment in here, my question how to see if event working or not ? i just change date in my localhost but nothing happen in database, where do i wrong here ? please don't vote down lah cause i'm new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mysql database lives on a web server, you can set up a cron job that runs at the first of every month. Your server probably provides some web interface to do this.

If you can't start the cron job from the server itself, there are free web services where you can set up cron jobs that call scripts on your server at given times.

The script called by the cron job can be a simple php script that runs the query.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_query(' /* insert query here */ ');
mysql_close($link);
```

You may want to include some error checking and either send yourself an email about success / failure or leave some messages in a log file. That way you can monitor whether the script runs at all and / or successfully.

Comment: I want to run it in the mysql only(means inside database only), not in php.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that was possible. That information was worth putting in a wrong answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `1` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (1);
```

Now, you create `plus_one` event which starts adding `1` to `num` every one month since `2023-11-01 00:00:00` as shown below. *If `2023-11-01 00:00:00` has already passed, `plus_one` event starts adding `1` to `num` every one month since `2023-12-01 00:00:00` after you create `plus_one` event. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057023/what-is-a-mysql-event/77489519#77489519) and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) explain events in MySQL:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT plus_one
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH
STARTS '2023-11-01 00:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can check `plus_one` event adds `1` to `num` every one month as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  2   |
+------+
```