# event is not working properly in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have created an event to execute first day of every month.

The event is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT event2
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2011-05-01 00:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
 call UpdateIt();
END$$

DELIMITER ;

/* Here Stored procedure "UpdateIt()" will update a row.*/
```

No Issue with the Stored procedure, its working fine.

And I have set the @@global.event_scheduler to 1.

Even though it is not working. Could any one sort out this issue, please.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know what "it's not working" is? Did you test it and if yes, how? What were the parameters of your test? How did you conclude it's not working? Are you sure it's the event that's not working or the procedure?

Comment: Start date is '2011-05-01', today is '2011-04-20'. Did you changed system date? And how? Try to test event using 1 MINUTE.

Comment: I have checked, Procedure is working fine but Event is not working properly. I have changed the system date and checked the table also no change in the table.

Comment: As I know, MySQL server should be restarted after changing system date.

Comment: @ Devart, Any other idea sir.

Comment: I created the same event, then changed system time to '2011-04-30 23:58:00', then restarted MySQL. It worked.

Comment: Yes @Devart, I too had restarted the Mysql but no result. I think I might have deleted the default mysql event unknowingly. Are there any default events in mysql???

Comment: Very strange. Run 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' to check if event_scheduler daemon is started. And - could you try to do it on another server?

Answer (score 0):

1- Create the event as stated in the question.

2- Change the system date to `'2011-04-30 23:58:00'`

3- Restart MySQL

MySQL needs to be restarted if you change the system date, or it will not detect the change.
Also note that if you have some sort of time-synchronization with a time-server you need to disable that or your server will revert to the real time before MySQL has a chance to finish the restart.

Comment: i have been follow your instruction but not working please goes to here if you are free http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400140/auto-add-field-each-user-using-event-nothing-error-and-doesnt-working