# Event won't trigger

Tags: mysql

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with this, I'm hoping someone here can point it out or at least point me in the right direction.  Here's my code in MySQL:

```
create event truncate_mainbak
on schedule
every 1 day
starts '2014-11-03 05:00:00' on completion preserve enable
do truncate mainbak_data;
```

All I want to do is perform a truncate operation on the table 'mainbak_data' once a day at the designated time.  Try as I might, this won't actually execute when I set it to a time in the immediate future.  I can manually initiate a `truncate mainbak_data` and it will work fine, but I can't get it to work as a scheduled event.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Try `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Comment: And make sure the startdate is (at the time of creating the event) in the future.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728996/event-is-not-working-properly-in-mysql: "Run 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' to check if event_scheduler daemon is started."

Comment: Bingo... event_scheduler wasn't even on!  Thanks @wolfgangwalther!!

Comment: Just posted it as an answer, as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the mysql event scheduler is running with:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Check whether the event_scheduler daemon is started.

If the deamon is not started, you can enable it with the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```