# What is a "MySQL event"?

Tags: mysql, database, cron, job-scheduling, mysql-event

What is a "MySQL event"? What is its purpose? How is it different from a "job scheduler"?

Many posts on SO, and the MySQL documentation, describe how to implement MySQL events, but I am just interested in their purpose.

Comment: Why do you think it should be different than a 'job scheduler'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MySQL events offer an alternative to `scheduled tasks` and `cron jobs`.

Events can be used to create backups, delete stale records, aggregate data for reports, and so on. Unlike standard triggers which execute given a certain condition, an event is an object that is triggered by the passage of time and is sometimes referred to as a temporal trigger.

Refer below link explained everything here :

http://phpmaster.com/working-with-mysql-events/

Comment: Thanks Teez - great answer :).  One additional question, it sounds like MySQL events only execute SQL commands. Do you know of a good job scheduler if I want to be executing a PHP script?

Comment: Thanks for the PHPmaster link, very helpful.

Comment: Suppose that I allow users to edit a thing (which has editable=true in the database) for 7 days. Would it be appropriate usage to set a MySQL event to set editable=false after 7 days? Or it should only be used for batch processing etc?

Answer (score 0):

An event is a scheduled task in MySQL. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) explains an event in detail.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `1` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (1);
```

Now, you can create `plus_one` event which starts adding `1` to `num` every one second since `2023-11-15 00:00:00` as shown below. *[CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) statement must have [DO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/do.html) statement and `DO` statement must have at least one SQL statement otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488351/creating-an-event-got-syntax-error-in-mysql/77492086#77492086) and if `2023-11-15 00:00:00` has already passed, `plus_one` event starts adding `1` to `num` every one second immediately just after you create `plus_one` event and basically, you need to change the default delimiter `;` to something like `$$` when creating an event otherwise there is error, then after creating an event, you need to change the delimiter `$$` back to `;` as shown below and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/77440483#77440483) explains delimiter and you must select a database when creating an event otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve/77491814#77491814):

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT plus_one
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2023-11-15 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can check `plus_one` event adds `1` to `num` every one second as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  23  |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  61  |
+------+
```

Be careful, even if you set [the user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) e.g. `@my_value` with `1`, then use it in an event as shown below:

```sql
SET @my_value = 1;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT plus_one
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2023-11-15 00:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = @my_value; -- Here
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, `@my_value` is `NULL` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT @my_value; 
+----------------------+
| @my_value            |
+----------------------+
| NULL                 |
+----------------------+
```

And, even if you define [the user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) e.g. `@my_value` with `Hello` in an event as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2023-11-15 00:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
SET @my_value = "Hello"; -- Here
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, `@my_value` is `NULL` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT @my_value; 
+----------------------+
| @my_value            |
+----------------------+
| NULL                 |
+----------------------+
```

In addition, in this case below, you can create `plus_one` event not changing the delimiter to `$$` without error:

```sql
CREATE EVENT plus_one
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2023-11-15 00:00:00'
DO 
UPDATE test SET num = num + 1;
```