# Creating an event got syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064, mysql-event

I'm trying to create this event but I can't find the syntax error.

```
CREATE 
EVENT respaldoRegRawInformeAperturaLocal
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-08-03 22:00:00' 
DO BEGIN

    -- INSERT INTO BACKUP TABLE
    INSERT INTO regRawInformeAperturaLocalBACKUP (regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId) 
    -- GET DATA
    SELECT regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId  
    FROM    regRawInformeAperturaLocal 
    WHERE regRawInformeAperturaLocal.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

    -- DELETE DATA FROM ORIGINAL TABLE
    DELETE FROM regRawInformeAperturaLocal WHERE regRawInformeAperturaLocal.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

END;
```

[CODE EDIT 1]

```
CREATE 
EVENT respaldoRegRawInformeAperturaLocal
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-08-03 22:00:00' 
DO BEGIN

    -- INSERT INTO BACKUP TABLE
    INSERT INTO regRawInformeAperturaLocalBACKUP (regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId) 
    -- GET DATA
    SELECT regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId  
    FROM    regRawInformeAperturaLocal 
    WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

    -- DELETE DATA FROM ORIGINAL TABLE
    DELETE FROM regRawInformeAperturaLocal WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

END;
```

[EDIT]
This is the syntax error message:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

Comment: post the error ..

Comment: Updated. It says it's on this string: "WHERE regRawInformeAperturaLocal.date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);"

Comment: why is `regRawInformeAperturaLocal.date`, not only `date` ?

Comment: Not that it matters, but why are you referencing the table name in the Where clause when you don't need to?

Comment: I updated the error. I always used by this way Is it a bad practice?

Comment: Just delete it and see

Comment: Remove it from the Delete statement as well. Just be consistent throughout your code.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code, The delete should work fine because If I use the same structure as a Select works perferct.

Comment: still getting same error?

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting the same error. There could be some issues with Mysql events + DATE_SUB function?

Comment: you want select data with 5 month ago ?

Comment: Yes, I need to backup the data older than 5 months and then delete it.

Comment: Have you tried using `DELIMITER`?.

Comment: Oh, no. I'm going to search about it

Comment: The DELIMITER was the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could make it work:

I have to add the **DELIMITER** and change the syntaxis from **END;** to **END|**

Anyway here's the code:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE 
    EVENT IF NOT EXISTS respaldoRegRawInformeAperturaLocal
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-08-03 22:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

    -- INSERT INTO BACKUP TABLE
    INSERT INTO regRawInformeAperturaLocalBACKUP (regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId) 
    -- GET DATA
    SELECT regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId  
    FROM    regRawInformeAperturaLocal 
    WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

    -- DELETE DATA FROM ORIGINAL TABLE
    DELETE FROM regRawInformeAperturaLocal WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I have to test it but I could create it so I guess It's fine.

[EDIT]
The event works like a charm.

Comment: Using a delimiter solved the issue for me on Amazon RDS with MySQL v5.7

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

When I didn't set [DO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/do.html) statement in the event `plus_one` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE EVENT plus_one
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2023-11-15 00:00:00';
```

Or, when I didn't set any SQL statements in `DO` statement in the event `plus_one` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE EVENT plus_one
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2023-11-15 00:00:00'
DO; -- Here
```

So, I set `DO` statement with a SQL statement as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE EVENT plus_one
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2023-11-15 00:00:00'
DO UPDATE test SET num = num + 1; -- Here
```